# Keeping wifi active during lock

Tags: network

So I can find no good solution to this. I have a macbook pro running yosemite that will take down the interface when I lock it. How can I configure it so the network connection stays active when the computer is locked?

Also note that recommendations to install "lock me now" as a workaround won't work, as that app isn't available in my area (according to the app store).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say "Lock" you mean that the screensaver kicks in so that you are prompted for a password.

I use an app called Amphetamine (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?l=en&mt=12). It will make sure your Mac stays awake, but still allow it to start the screensaver (ie locking it). This way, any network activity continues (downloads, streaming, etc.), but your Mac is password protected.

Comment: No, not the screensaver. When I say lock, I mean lock. Press control shift power and you will know what lock does.

Comment: That's actually just putting the display to sleep. I just tried it and network activity continues even after putting the display to sleep. What I think is happening is that your Mac sleeps based on System Preferences -> Energy Saver -> Computer sleep. Could you verify what that is set to? You could just set it to Never and it works the same way.

Comment: Sorry, you confused me when you said screen saver, as it actually just turns the screen off. You could be correct. I've gone into the computer sleep settings and changed a few things; now i don't seem to bounce from irc. Will keep testing. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, any thoughts on keeping network up even if I close the laptop lid?

Comment: There are ways to disable sleep when closing the lid. But I believe that runs into overheating issues since you're essentially cutting airflow. I don't recommend it. Even the setting to disable Computer Sleep above won't stop sleeping when closing the lid I believe.